# Probability of 3-character string appearing in a randomly generated password

Tags: math, passwords, probability

If you have a randomly generated password, consisting of only alphanumeric characters, of length 12, and the comparison is case insensitive (i.e. 'A' == 'a'), what is the probability that one specific string of length 3 (e.g. 'ABC') will appear in that password?

I know the number of total possible combinations is (26+10)^12, but beyond that, I'm a little lost.  An explanation of the math would also be most helpful.

Comment: Also this question belongs to `http://math.stackexchange.com/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The string "abc" can appear in the first position, making the string look like this:

```
abcXXXXXXXXX
```

...where the X's can be any letter or number.  There are (26 + 10)^9 such strings.

It can appear in the second position, making the string look like:

```
XabcXXXXXXXX
```

And there are (26 + 10)^9 such strings also.

Since "abc" can appear at anywhere from the first through 10th positions, there are 10*36^9 such strings.

But this overcounts, because it counts (for instance) strings like this twice:

```
abcXXXabcXXX
```

So we need to count all of the strings like this and subtract them off of our total.

Since there are 6 X's in this pattern, there are 36^6 strings that match this pattern.

I get 7+6+5+4+3+2+1 = 28 patterns like this.  (If the first "abc" is at the beginning, the second can be in any of 7 places.  If the first "abc" is in the second place, the second can be in any of 6 places.  And so on.)

So subtract off 28*36^6.

...but that subtracts off too much, because it subtracted off strings like this three times instead of just once:

```
abcXabcXabcX
```

So we have to add back in the strings like this, twice.  I get 4+3+2+1 + 3+2+1 + 2+1 + 1 = 20 of these patterns, meaning we have to add back in 2*20*(36^3).

But that math counted this string four times:

```
abcabcabcabc
```

...so we have to subtract off 3.

Final answer:

```
10*36^9 - 28*36^6 + 2*20*(36^3) - 3
```

Divide that by 36^12 to get your probability.

See also the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).   And let me know if I made an error in my counting.

Comment: @Jason: Thanks.  Sorry if my comments got a little heated.  Now I just wonder who downvoted me :-).  Also, I think you should undelete your answer and put a disclaimer at the end like tskuzzy did.  Your approach is more accurate than the others, I think, and it is certainly simpler than the full analysis.

Comment: That `28*10^6` should be `28*36^6`.

Comment: @Nemo: It's fine. SIWOTI syndrome IMO.

Comment: Note that this gives an answer which is almost identical numerically to that given by my earlier solution (0.0002143), which I've now been forced to delete due to obnoxious down-voting: <http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2810*36%5E9+-+28*36%5E6+%2B+2*20*%2836%5E3%29+-+3%29%2F36%5E12>

Comment: @Paul:  Add a disclaimer like tskuzzy's, including the Wolfram Alpha link etc., and I for one will remove my downvote (as I did for his).  I only downvoted your answer because it was wrong.

Comment: @Nemo: too late now - your criticism and down-vote apparently started a down-voting feeding frenzy on mine and other similar answers, which are all now deleted. As for being wrong - yes, probably, but a difference in the ninth decimal place is probably way more than the required accuracy in this context, where an order of magnitude is probably all that is needed.

Comment: @Paul: There is nothing wrong with an approximation, as long as you are aware you are making an approximation.  Had your answer shown that awareness, I would not have downvoted it.  As written, it was wrong, so I hit the down button and explained why.  If you think that was inappropriate, I am willing to listen, here or in chat.

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is not equal to `C`, the probability `P(n)` of `ABC` occuring in a string of length `n` (assuming every alphanumeric symbol is equally likely) is

```
P(n)=P(n-1)+P(3)[1-P(n-3)]
```

where

```
P(0)=P(1)=P(2)=0 and P(3)=1/(36)^3
```

Answer (score -2):

To expand on Paul R's answer. Probability (for equally likely outcomes) is the number of possible outcomes of your event divided by the total number of possible outcomes.

There are 10 possible places where a string of length 3 can be found in a string of length 12. And there are 9 more spots that can be filled with any other alphanumeric characters, which leads to `36^9` possibilities. So the number of possible outcomes of your event is `10 * 36^9`.

Divide that by your total number of outcomes `36^12`. And your answer is `10 * 36^-3 = 0.000214`

EDIT: This is not completely correct. In this solution, some cases are double counted. However they only form a very small contribution to the probability so this answer is still correct up to 11 decimal places. If you want the full answer, see Nemo's answer.

Comment: This is not correct.  Please see my comment on @Paul's answer.

Comment: @Nemo: Thanks for pointing out the error. I will think about it a little more.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I made an invalid inference :-)

Comment: Note that @Nemo's more pedantic answer gives a numerical result which matches to 8 decimal places.